# MYSL: How to keep duplicates if they have different X?

Tags: mysql, mariadb

This is my query

```
SELECT * FROM( 
    SELECT orderid, duration, is_renew, bundle_id, service_id, object_name, pkg_id_fk, disconnect_time, DATE_ADD(paid_on, INTERVAL duration HOUR) AS expires
    FROM wtb_orders WHERE username= :username AND is_paid=1 AND is_revoked=0
    HAVING (expires + INTERVAL :retry_rate DAY) >= NOW()
    ORDER BY expires DESC LIMIT 300)
    as tmp GROUP BY 
    tmp.pkg_id_fk, 
    tmp.bundle_id,
    tmp.service_id
```

I want to:

- Keep duplicate `pkg_id_fk` if the other duplicate has a different duration
- Keep duplicate `bundle_id` if the other duplicate has a different duration
- Keep duplicate `service_id` if the other duplicate has a different duration

Everything else about the query is correct and I don't want to change anything else. It's just that `group_by` remove duplicates and I don't know how to keep certain duplicates from being removed.

if you need to see the DB schema, [here](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=mysql_5.7&fiddle=e50d78aa4083fbaf8d8062f0a8ccd668), you just need to look at `wtb_orders`

Comment: Add `duration` to GROUP BY expression...

Comment: @Akina would that really work? wouldn't group_by already have removed the duplicates? Or wouldn't it remove `bundle_id` and `service_id` having the same duration?

Comment: I don't understand your words. While `GROUP BY pkg_id_fk, bundle_id, service_id, duration`, if at least one field differs you'll obtain separate grouip. PS. And looking at *if you need to see the DB schema, [here](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=mysql_5.7&fiddle=e50d78aa4083fbaf8d8062f0a8ccd668), you just need to look at `wtb_orders`* I see only *Unknown column 'tmp.pkg_id_fk' in 'group statement'*. And do not see the query text posted. Please synchronize...